# Ruby On rails form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I've created a contact mailer, within my ruby on rails app, and wish to validate that the email being entered, is indeed an e-mail, and that the other fields have been filled.

I've downloaded and installed `gem jquery-validation-rails`

Here is my `contact.html.erb` file, I cannot see what is missing!?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

      <h1>Contact Us</h1>
      <p>Complete the following form</p>
      <%= form_tag request_contact_path, method: 'post' do %>
      <br>
      <%= label_tag :name, "Name" %>
      <%= text_field :name, :class => "required"%>
      <br>  
      <%= label_tag :email, "Email" %>
      <%= text_field :email, :class => "required email"%>
      <br> 
      <%= label_tag :telephone, "Telephone" %>
      <%= text_field :telephone, :class => "required"%>
      <br> 
      <%= label_tag :message, "Message" %>
      <%= text_field :telephone, :class => "required"%>
      <br>  
      <%= submit_tag "Submit", name: nil %>
      <% end %>
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function () { 
              $("request_contact_path").validate();  
          });
      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I appreciate any feedback on this as I am new to both ruby on rails and jquery.

Comment: if you could paste the rendered output for the html it would help in troubleshooting if the error is on js side

Answer (score 0):

First of all `$("request_contact_path").validate();` shouldnt have a `#` or `.` appended to it like `$("#request_contact_path").validate();` ?.

Second, the [JqueryValidate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/) requires the field to be of `type=email` to validate the input against a valid email and the `required` attribute to make a field required, I am not a `ROR` guy so pardon me if I am wrong here, but looking at the code it looks like you are assigning the `email` to `class` attribute of the input

```
<%= text_field :email, :class => "required email"%>
```

change it to render the input in this format

```
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" required="" aria-required="true">
```